# Hover over one div and change another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I am completely lost here and need some mad help.

If you click here http://cdechmedia.com/WIP/
You will see three cards one form wow,LoL and wildstar.

As you can see by the background that it is an empty land.

What I am trying to do is whenever I hover over say the wow card the empty land will turn into another image.

I am at a loss of how to do this. Honestly I don't care if it's just with CSS , Javascript, or whatever as long and I can make it happen.

Here is the CSS for the cards an background:

```
<div class="GMSpash">
 <div class="CardsWrapper">
  <a href="#">
  <div class="WoWCard"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="LoLCard"></div></a>
  <a href="#"><div class="WSCard"></div></a>
 </div>
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
.GMSpash {
    height: 656px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: url(images/GMSplashBG.jpg);
}
.LoLSplash {
    height: 656px;
    width: 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    background-image: url(images/WSSplashBG.jpg);
}
.CardsWrapper {
    height: 348px;
    width: 719px;
    margin-top: 450px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -359.5px;
    left: 50%;
}
.WoWCard{
    background-image: url(images/WoWcard.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 348px;
    width: 237px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transition:  all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition:  all 0.4s;
    -o-transition:  all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition:  all 0.4s;
    transition:  all 0.4s;
}
.WoWCard:hover {
    background-image: url(images/WoWcardH.png);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.LoLCard {
    background-image: url(images/LoLcard.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 348px;
    width: 237px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.LoLCard:hover {
    background-image: url(images/LoLcardH.png);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
.WSCard {
    background-image: url(images/WScard.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    height: 348px;
    width: 237px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.WSCard:hover {
    background-image: url(images/WScardH.png);
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

Now as you can see there is a class that says `.LoLSplash` so when I hover over the league card it will turn the `GMSpash` to `LoLSplash`.

I have tried the `#a:hover + #b` and `#a:hover ~ #b`  but for some reason it isn't working for me and I'm truly at a loss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change your `<div class="WoWCard"></div>` to add an `onmousemove` and an `onmouseleave` like `<div class="WoWCard" onmousemove='setBackgroundWOW()' onmouseleave='setBackgroundDefault()'></div>`, and give your div `<div class="GMSpash">` an id like `<div class="GMSpash" id='gmspash'>`then it should be easy to set the background with a simple javascript function:

```
<script>
function setBackgroundWOW(){
    document.getElementById("gmspash").style.backgroundImage = "url('wow_image_url')";
}
function setBackgroundDefault(){
    document.getElementById("gmspash").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/GMSplashBG.jpg')";
}
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: This worked perfect one last question is how do I make it fade in and out nicely and then I'm golden. thank you soo much man.

Comment: If you add the following code to your "GMSpash" class:

`-webkit-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;
transition: background-image 0.2s ease-in-out;`

then the fading should work perfectly. Don't forget to accept the answer!

Comment: Hmm that doesn't seem to work still still not fading any other ideas.http://cdechmedia.com/WIP/

Comment: What browser are you using? I've just had a look, and it seems like the issue is coming from the fact that the images you are using are very large and take a while to load. There aren't many ways to solve that, aside from using another kind of transition, like a slide across. If you wanted to use a slide across it would be very easy to make a smooth and cross-browser implementation.

Comment: no i want it to fade in and out and im your firefox. that being said when i make a link for the image using the fading it worked just fine so hmm i wonder what the issue could be.....

Comment: hmm i notice it fades in Google chrome but not Firefox and in 10 hmm wonder why?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want something like this.

```
$(".CardsWrapper > a").mouseover(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.children.hassClass("WoWCard")) {
        $(".CardsWrapper").parent().removeClass().addClass("WoWSplash");
    }
    else if ($this.children.hassClass("LoLCard")) {
        $(".CardsWrapper").parent().removeClass().addClass("LoLSplash");
    }
    else if ($this.children.hassClass("WSCard")) {
        $(".CardsWrapper").parent().removeClass().addClass("WSSplash");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set an "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" for the specific card like this:

```
<div id="LoLCard" class="LoLCard" onmouseover="changeLoLBackground()" onmouseout="resetLoLBackground()"></div>
```

and in JS:

```
    function changeLoLBackground() {
       document.getElementById("LoLCard").style.backgroundImage = 'url(URLofYourNewImage)';
    }
    function resetLoLBackground() {
       document.getElementById("LoLCard").style.backgroundImage = 'url(URLofYourOrgImage)';
    }
```

If you meant the background image of the website replace

```
document.getElementById("LoLCard")
```

with the id of your background div.